# C# Streamreader reading line which doesn't exist?

Tags: c#

I want to read a `.csv` file and store is data in a Datatable, but for some reason the code is trowing an error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

`line` was null.

I already debugged and search what was the error which is, after reading last line lets say line - 194 of CSV which contain values, and after reading that line he is going to read "another" line 195 which is null because that line doesn't exist in my CSV file and it reads that don't know why. I already tried to open notepad and delete the extra line I got and save it and keeps give me the same error - any help?

Here is my code:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new streamReader(@"PATH"))
    {
        var datatable = new DataTable();
        datatable.Columns.Add("PowerPlantId", typeof(string));
        datatable.Columns.Add("AssetId", typeof(int));
        string line;

        line = sr.ReadLine();
        if (line != null)
        {
            do
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line + "\n");
                string[] lineitems = line.Split(",");
                DataRow dr = datatable.NewRow();
                dr["PowerPlantId"] = lineitems[0];
                dr["AssetId"] = lineitems[1];
                datatable.Rows.Add(dr);
            } while (line != null);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the steps happening in your `do-while` loop:

- Calling `ReadLine()`
- Processing the line
- Checking for null and repeat

What should happen instead:

- Calling `ReadLine()`
- Checking for null
- Processing the line

You are getting a `NRE` because order of events is wrong.

You can change your loop to `while` instead:

```
while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
     // process line, do NOT call ReadLine!
}
```

Comment: The extra read line which is ignoring a line is presumably just ignoring the header row and doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem at hand. I think opening with that is distracting from the actual problem that you then go onto explain. I'd suggest the answer might be better without that first sentence...

Comment: @Chris you are absolutely right, I realized it as well. I have revised my answer, thx.